# How to remove preceding zeros in version numbers with alphabets using python?

Tags: python

I have to read version numbers from a couple of servers and remove preceding 0s from it to match with expected version number.
My version number from server looks like these

```
15.04.03a 
4.05.03.034I
12.09.02a
4.09.1.028I
```

so I'm expecting output to be like `15.4.3a` and so on.

I have the below in which works well if there is no character, but doesnt work when there is a character

```
s = "17.05.03a"
print(".".join(str(int(i)) for i in s.split(".")))
```

How can I change it to include characters as well ?

Comment: Like `\.0+` and then replace with `.` ? See https://regex101.com/r/sPbmeb/1

Comment: Why do you need `int()`, when you're going to have letters?

Comment: If any of the answers below solved your issue, then consider marking the one that best helped you as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

inputs = [
  '15.04.03a',
  '4.05.03.034I',
  '12.09.02a',
  '4.09.1.028I'
]

for s in inputs:
  # Replace any leading zeros that are followed by a digit
  print(re.sub(r'\b0+(?=\d)', '', s))
```

Output:

```
15.4.3a
4.5.3.34I
12.9.2a
4.9.1.28I
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this RegEx:

```
import re

s = '15.04.03a'
new = re.sub(r'\.0+', '.', s)
print(new)
```

Explanation:

- `\.` will match a `.` character
- `0+` will match one or more `0` characters

Then the `re.sub()` function will replace the whole match with a single `.`, in effect removing all the `0`s matched.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to remove all trailing zeroes, possibly leaving a trailing dot, you can assert a digit 1-9 after matching the zeroes:

```
(?<=\d\.)0+(?=[1-9])
```

Or if you could also have `.00015.04.03a` omit the digit in the lookbehind:

```
(?<=\.)0+(?=[1-9])
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\d\.)` Positive lookbehind, assert a digit followed by a dot directly to the left
- `0+` Match 1+ times a zero
- `(?=[1-9])` Assert a digit 1-9 to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z9CNxw/1).

```
import re
 
strings = [
    "15.04.03a ",
    "4.05.03.034I",
    "12.09.02a",
    "4.09.1.028I",
    "1.00001.00",
    "0.00.0001"
]
 
for s in strings:
    print(re.sub(r"(?<=\d\.)0+(?=[1-9])", "", s))
```

Output

```
15.4.3a 
4.5.3.34I
12.9.2a
4.9.1.28I
1.1.00
0.00.1
```

---

If the version number must end with a char A-Za-z, and then followed by a whitespace boundary:

```
 (?<=\d\.)0+(?=[1-9][\d.]*[A-Za-z]+(?!\S))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K8khsL/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use comprehension the way you have given.

```
s = "17.05.03a"
print(".".join(x.lstrip('0') for x in s.split(".")))
```